# Paste data on last row of input sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Im creating a macro which pulls data from several columns on several sheets and organize all data into one sheet.

The code i have is :

```
Private Sub Update_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim path As String, fileName As String
    Dim lastRowInput As Long, lastRowOutput As Long, rowCntr As Long, lastColumn As Long
    Dim inputWS1 As Worksheet, inputWS2 As Worksheet, outputWS As Worksheet

    'set your sheets here
    Set inputWS1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Universal")
    Set inputWS2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Geovera")
    Set outputWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Carriers")


    rowCntr = 1

    'get last rows from both sheets
    lastRowUniversal = inputWS1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowGeovera = inputWS2.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowPolicy = outputWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    lastRowOutput = outputWS.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastColumn = inputWS1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Universal
    inputWS1.Range("A4:A" & lastRowUniversal).Copy outputWS.Range("B2")
    inputWS1.Range("B4:B" & lastRowUniversal).Copy outputWS.Range("C2")
    outputWS.Range("E2:E" & (lastRowUniversal - 2)).Value = inputWS1.Name
    inputWS1.Range("J4:J" & lastRowUniversal).Copy outputWS.Range("G2")
    outputWS.Range("G2:G" & (lastRowUniversal - 2)).Value = Evaluate("=IF(ISNUMBER(G2:G" & (lastRowUniversal - 2) & "),DATE(YEAR(G2:G" & (lastRowUniversal - 2) & ")-1,MONTH(G2:G" & (lastRowUniversal - 2) & "),DAY(G2:G" & lastRowUniversal & ")),G2:G" & (lastRowUniversal - 2) & ")")
    inputWS1.Range("G4:G" & lastRowUniversal).Copy outputWS.Range("H2")

    'Geovera
    inputWS2.Range("F2:F" & lastRowOutput).Copy outputWS.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 
End Sub
```

I finished working on migrating one sheet to the organized main sheet.

When i start setting up the 2nd sheet i noticed that it overwrites the data from the first sheet. I want a code that will paste the data at the first blank space on the row.

My error is coming at this line:

```
inputWS2.Range("F2:F" & lastRowOutput).Copy outputWS.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
```

is still not there. But i want the data from column F to move to column B on the main sheet without deleting what i already copied on the previous sheet.

Please help

Comment: which sheet do you want to copy the the data to... im a little confused because `lastRowOutput` is referencing `Carriers` sheet but you have the variable where you are grabbing information from the `Geovera` sheet.

Comment: What if you just try inputWS2.Range("F2:F" & lastRowOutput).Copy outputWS.Range("B65536") without the .end(xlUp).row?  It doesn't give an error on my sheet.

Comment: Hey @ShanayL, im trying to copy the data to Carrier. the Lastrowoutput variable was put on the last line by me trying to tweak it out.

Comment: @CDVAProgrammer That didnt work.

Comment: I think it would help to see an example data set, ie how does the first two input sheets look like and also see how the output sheet is supposed to be.

Comment: Here is a shareable link.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6iO6tzl38BqRDA1SWZ1QjM5Wnc

last line messed up my code on the Carriers sheet which is my main sheet and were i want ALL data to go to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
inputWS2.Range("F2:F" & lastRowOutput).Copy outputWS.Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row
```

try

```
inputWS2.Range("F2:F" & lastRowGeovera).Copy outputWS.Range("B" & lastRowUniversal - 1)
```